# Encryption not works in >5.6.0

Tags: php, encryption, php-5.6

I've created my own encryption class, using `mcrypt_encrypt` is working fine but `mcrypt_decrypt` is not working as expected. So here's the following code

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Encryption {

    private $key = "myKeyIs";
    protected $iv_size;
    protected $iv;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    public function encryptData($input) {
        $input = $input;
        $output = $this->encrypt($input);
        return $output;
    }

    public function decryptData($input) {
        $input = base64_decode($input);
        $output = $this->decrypt($input);
        return $output;
    }

    public function decrypt($string) {
        $string = base64_decode($string);
        # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
        $iv_dec = substr($string, 0, $this->iv_size);

        # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
        $string = substr($string, $this->iv_size);

        # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
        $output = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key,
                                        $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
        return $output;
    }

    public function encrypt($string) {

        $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key,
                                 $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);

        # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
        $output = $this->iv . $output;

        # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
        $output = base64_encode($output);

        return $output;
    }

}

$test = new Encryption();
$encrypted  = $test->encryptData("Vicky");
echo $encrypted."\n";
echo $test->decryptData($encrypted);
```

**Output**

```
hCaIoMokbIjLlnFnlrS3Iw==
�M����+�=�lØ�
```

Now the questions are

1. Why its not decrypting as expected?
2. Why its not outputting any text above PHP versions 5.6.0. You can
   check over [**here**](https://3v4l.org/aBDWW) for the version output.

Comment: The problem is that you used `error_reporting(1)`, which does not do what you likely expect it to do. It will disable nearly all errors. You're looking for `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. With that, you should see a warning explaining why the call fails (wrong key size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've identified some bugs and its working well in PHP versions above 5.3.29

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Encryption {

    private $key;
    protected $iv_size;
    protected $iv;

    public function __construct() {
        # --- ENCRYPTION ---
        # the key should be random binary, use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 to
        # convert a string into a key
        # key is specified using hexadecimal
        $this->key = pack("H*", "myKeyIsGreaterth2nanndbestofall04nkdsdffsd546754sdfvsdg6efflsdfs");
        # create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
        $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    public function encryptData($input) {
        $output = $this->encrypt($input);
        return $output;
    }

    public function decryptData($input) {
        $input = base64_decode($input);
        $output = $this->decrypt($input);
        return $output;
    }

    protected function decrypt($string) {

        # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
        $iv_dec = substr($string, 0, $this->iv_size);

        # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
        $string = substr($string, $this->iv_size);

        # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
        $output = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

        return $output;
    }

    protected function encrypt($string) {
        # creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
        # to keep the text confidential 
        # only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
        # (because of default zero padding)
        $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);

        # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
        $output = $this->iv . $output;

        # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
        $output = base64_encode($output);

        # === WARNING ===
        # Resulting cipher text has no integrity or authenticity added
        # and is not protected against padding oracle attacks.

        return $output;
    }

}

$test = new Encryption();
$encrypted = $test->encryptData("Vicky");
echo "This is encrypted text of a string Vicky  $encrypted \n";
echo "This is decrypted text ".$test->decryptData($encrypted);
```

Update that I've done are as

1. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` instead of `error_reporting(1);`
2. Used `pack` function for key // If you don't want to use `pack` you can simply use key Size of `16, 24 or 32`
3. Update `mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,` into `mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size,`
4. Removed extra `base64_decode($string);` from `decrypt` function

So its now ready to use just update your own key

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/l187L)